# Get all checklists for all cards in Trello

Tags: javascript, trello

Is it possible to get every checklist within every card where I am a member in one API-requiest.
Ideally, I would like to use the following path:

```
Trello.get('members/me/cards/all/checklists', function(checklist) { ... });
```

Is it possible to accomplish in one request?

Comment: Did you see this https://trello.com/docs/api/checklist/?

Comment: Yes, I did. It doesn't help to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about https://trello.com/1/members/me/cards?checklists=all&fields=none

I used `fields=none` to make the checklists easier to see visually, but if you also want other data from the cards you can of course change that.

I built this URL based on the documentation at https://trello.com/docs/api/member/index.html#get-1-members-idmember-or-username-cards